# clr.AddReferenceToFile() fails in IronPython 2.7

Tags: python, ironpython

Can someone explain why this code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32")

import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("wiimotelib.dll")
```

works fine with IronPython 2.6, but fails in IronPython 2.7 alpha 1 with an IOException, and the message:

```
Could not add reference to assembly wiimotelib.dll
```

Is this new behaviour in 2.7, or is it an alpha release bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be a .NET 2 vs .NET 4 problem?  IronPython 2.7A1 is .NET 4.0 only.  2.6 had both .NET 2 and .NET 4 versions.  If the assembly is a .NET 2 assembly it might not load on the .NET 4 CLR.

Comment: The DLL is well over a year old, so it won't be .NET 4. Guess I'll have to hope a newer version comes out one day.

Answer (score 2):

You have to recompile the WiimoteLib Assembly. I've had the same problem. After recompilation it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think in IronPython 2.7 was removed the need for the "DLL" extension:

You could try: `clr.AddReferenceToFile("wiimotelib");`

Worked for me.